# Convert SQL To Relational Algebra - Find how many suppliers supply some red part

Tags: sql, database, computer-science, relational-algebra

Suppliers(sid: integer, sname: string, address: string)
Parts(pid: integer, pname: string, color: string)
Catalog(sid: integer, pid: integer, cost: real)

**Write the following query in relational algebra:

- Find how many suppliers supply some red part.**

I have the sql query but I am having trouble converting it to relational algebra.

SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(Suppliers.sid)  
FROM Parts, Catalog  
WHERE Suppliers.sid = Catalog.sid AND Parts.color = 'Red'  
GROUP BY Suppliers.sid
```

Comment: The SQL query does not appear to be correct. Would you please post a link to http://sqlfiddle.com/ showing your tables and query?

Comment: Please read [ask] and hits googling 'stackexchange.com homework'. *Explain* your "trouble", what you have done & where you are stuck. If are composing RA (relational algebra) expressions by converting from SQL, what is your plan for doing that, or a reference you are following? Otherwise, you are just asking us to rewrite a textbook section with a specialized example, which is too broad. Also *what version* of RA? There are many. Give a reference or description. Also since you are asking about code--SQL, but RA expressions are also code--please read & act on [mcve]. PS Google your title.

Comment: The SQL query definitely isn't correct. Which tables do you think you're querying? Why? (This schema is a rip-off of the Suppliers & Parts schema used in Date's textbooks.)